# Press enter to click a LinkLabel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I have a linklabel on a .net winform, is there anyway I can, *when the link label is focused*, get a press of the `enter` key to cause said `LinkLabel` to click?

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to expose a `KeyDown` event.

---

**EDIT**

The simplest solution is to use `PreviewKeyDown`, if anyone happens to Google here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own link label class which extends the LinkLabel and overrides the OnKeyUp or OnKeyDown event to capture the ENTER keypress.

That would save you reproducing the code for every link label you add to your form.

e.g.

```
public class LinkLabelEx : LinkLabel
{

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            e.Handled = true;
            OnLinkClicked(new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs(new Link(0, this.Text.Length)));
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think the `PreviewKeyDown`, which I was too stupid to miss, is probably the best bet.  I'll +1 you after my votes reset in about an hour

Comment: Would it not be easier to add an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: @FreeAslnBeer - extension methods are cool, I was looking for an event to capture a key down.  I don't see how that could have helped me.

Comment: Thanks again for the sharp answer  +1 as promised :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a function for the logic placed behind your `LinkLabel` click event. Then you can use the [keyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.keydown%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event to call the same function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is no KeyDown event in LinkLabel; that was the problem from the beginning.  Fortunately though I did manage to find the PreviewKeyDown event which works just fine.